# Obter usuário do Windows através do PHP

Tags: php, apache, windows, login

É possível obter o login do usuário do computador a partir do PHP? O sistema que estou desenvolvendo é para uma intranet, então para que o usuário se logue, bastaria comparar o usuário que está logado com os usuários do banco de dados, caso não, ele não poderia logar. Alguma forma de fazer isso?

Estou utilizando o PHP num servidor web Apache e as maquinas da minha Intranet estão ligadas e um domínio.

Comment: Numa pesquisa rápida, aparentemente com PHP não, mas sim [com JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2968690/1287812)

Comment: Não encontrei nada concreto.

Comment: Acredito que seja uma vulnerabilidade deixar um script descobrir o username do usuario... Terá que seguir por outro caminho... Chutando talvez um applet ou extension do browser...

Comment: Enconrei [esse outro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768185/use-windows-username-in-html) stack no SO inglês com um *snippet* que usa um objeto ActiveX, mas não sei se o resultado é o que deveria ser. Além de rodar só no IEca, aqui mostrou apenas *function ActiveXObject() { [native code] }*

Comment: É, eu achei esse que usa o ActiveX, e realmente só roda no IE :/

Comment: Sua intranet está em um domínio? Se sim é possível através do webserver (Apache ou IIS)

Comment: @gmsantos Tá em um domínio sim. Como faço dessa maneira então?

Comment: Apache ou IIS??

Comment: @gmsantos Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que o que você queira chama-se [*Single Sign-On*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (SSO), isto é, a habilidade do usuário  realizar a autenticação uma única vez e, a partir daí, todos os sistemas compartilharem a informação de *login*.

Na web, o compartilhamento de autenticação é comum através do padrão aberto OpenID. É o caso do "Login com Google" ou "Login com Facebook" ou "Login com Twitter" que muitos sites disponibilizam.

Em intranets, é muito comum os sistemas realizarem o SSO utilizando o protocolo [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) num serviço [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) (Windows).

Entretanto, nem sempre o SSO provê um login transparente ao usuário, isto é, muitas implementações exigem que o usuário redigite as suas credenciais a cada autenticação.

Fiz uma pesquisa por "php sso active directory transparent login" e cheguei até [este post do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257024/apache2-php-sso-with-active-directory), através do qual cheguei até [esta página](http://www.grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/) sobre uma extensão do Apache chamada **mod_auth_kerb**.

Não sou especialista em redes nem em Windows Server, mas já aviso que implementar toda a infraestrutura necessário pode ser um processo bem trabalhoso e complicado.

Claro, você pode fazer alguma outra gambiarra que pegue simplesmente o nome de usuário de algum lugar, mas aí a segurança vai por água abaixo.

Comment: Não preciso me preocupar tanto com segurança porque o sistema vai ser usado por alguns poucos usuários leigos. O problema é que o orgão onde trabalho, os administradores da rede não liberam a conexão com o LDAP. Pedi o acesso e eles não liberam.

Comment: @JoãoNeto Nesse caso, se cada usuário tiver uma máquina fixa, você pode fazer a autenticação pelo IP. Ou ainda pode colocar um programa em background na máquina do usuário que responde ao servidor o nome do usuário, aí você faz uma requisição do servidor ao cliente para consultar o usuário pelo IP. Se não há preocupação com segurança, a criatividade é o limite.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando o Apache 2.4 é possível utilizar o módulo [mod_authn_ntlm](https://github.com/TQsoft-GmbH/mod_authn_ntlm).
Supondo que o controlador de domínio está configurado para receber requisições `ntlm`, execute os seguintes passos:

1 - Extraia o arquivo `mod_authn_ntlm.so` na pasta de módulos do seu Apache

2 - No seu `httpd.conf` insira a seguinte linha para carregar o módulo:

```
 LoadModule auth_ntlm_module modules/mod_authn_ntlm.so
```

3 - Esse módulo tem como dependência o `ldap_module`. Como ele já vem incluído no Apache, basta descomentar a seguinte linha no `httpd.conf`

```
 LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
```

4 - Por fim, na configuração do seu site, insira a seguinte configuração apontando no diretório dos seus scripts:

```
 <Location /path/para/seu/htdocs >
    AllowOverride None
    AuthName "Private location"
    AuthType SSPI
    NTLMAuth On
    NTLMAuthoritative On
    require valid-user
    #require sspi-user EMEA\group_name
 </Location>
```

4 - No seu script PHP, utilize a variável `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`, ela conterá o login no formato `dominio\usurario`

Comment: O passo 4 é dentro do httpd.conf ainda? Em que lugar que vai?

Comment: Pode ser no httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente não, pois o PHP é uma [linguagem de servidor](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_server-side).

Uma alternativa, porém limitada ao **Internet Explorer**, é usar JavaScript para obter essa informação com [Activex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Windows Username</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    alert(WinNetwork.UserName); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>[**Fonte** do Código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518490/1608936)</sub>

Comment: Acho que ele não quer o usuário do servidor... Ele quer o nome do usuário final do sistema.

Comment: Eu achei uma solução assim. Mas o problema é que não posso exigir que os funcionários usem apenas o IE. Mas obrigado pela disposição.

Answer (score 0):

para pegar o usuraio logado em um computador com PHP pode utilizar a seguinte função

```
<?php
    exec('wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName', $user);

    print_r($user[1]);
?>
```